# Symfony 1.4 Tasks Cannot Access Classes

Tags: php, symfony1, task, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to run a Symfony task but when i try to instantiate a class i get a fatal error.

The class is located in

- Apps

  - MyApp

    - lib

My code is as follows

```
 protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    $this->reloadAutoload();

    // initialize the database connection
    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
    $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();

    // Get file from dir
    if(!in_array($arguments['filename'] . $this->fileExt, scandir($this->path))) {
      $this->logSection('Import CSV', 'File doesn\'t exist.', null, 'ERROR');
      return;
    }

    $path = $this->path . '/' . $arguments['filename'] . $this->fileExt;

    if(class_exists('CsvReader')) {
      $csvReader = new CsvReader($path);
    } else {
      $this->logSection('Import CSV', 'Class doesn\'t exist.', null, 'ERROR');
      return;
    }

    // add your code here
    $this->logSection('Import CSV', 'All content imported.');
  }
```

If there is anything i'm missing then let me know and i'll amend my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things that might be preventing you from calling a class in your app:

1. You need to refresh your cache with `php symfony cc`
2. Your Symfony autoloader fails to find your class because the filename does not end with `.class.php`

Source: [Documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code#chapter_02_sub_class_autoloading)

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your reply. I done both of those and it still couldn't instantiate. I've just gone for the old skool way and just used require_once to get the job done.